# Remove space in empty node so that draw line is connected

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm trying to remove the white space that appears between two lines as a result of going to an empty node. Specifically, I have a node drawing to the left of the empty node and then the empty node drawing to the a new full node.

I've already used inner sep=0 and outer sep=0 on the node to reduce the empty gap. However,a small sliver still remains.

I need to have the empty node there for space reasons.

Image:
[image: empty location]

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}%pictures
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[auto,>=latex'] 
    \tikzstyle{block} = [draw, shape=rectangle, minimum height=3em, minimum width=3em, node distance=2cm, line width=1pt]
    \tikzstyle{sum} = [draw, shape=circle, node distance=1.5cm, line width=1pt, minimum width=1.25em]
    \tikzstyle{connection}=[inner sep=0,outer sep=0]
 %Creating Blocks and Connection Nodes
\node [block, right of=input] (h1) {$0.99$};
 \node [right of=h1] (hsum) {};
    \node [connection, right of=hsum] (cont) {};
    \path (h1) -- coordinate (hmed) (h1);
    %Connecting Blocks
    \begin{scope}[line width=1pt]
         \draw (input) -- (h1);\draw (h1) -- (cont);
    \end{scope}
 %Creating Blocks and Connection Nodes
\node [block, right of=cont] (m1) {$0.18$};\node [block, right of=m1] (m2) {$0.16$};
 \node [right of=m2] (msum) {};
    \node [connection, right of=msum] (output) {};
    \path (m1) -- coordinate (mmed) (m2);
    %Connecting Blocks
    \begin{scope}[line width=1pt]
         \draw (cont) -- (m1);\draw (m1) -- (m2);\draw (m2) -- (output);
    \end{scope}
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use a `coordinate` like

```
\coordinate[right of=hsum] (cont);
```

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}%pictures
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[auto,>=latex']
    \tikzstyle{block} = [draw, shape=rectangle, minimum height=3em, minimum width=3em, node distance=2cm, line width=1pt]
    \tikzstyle{sum} = [draw, shape=circle, node distance=1.5cm, line width=1pt, minimum width=1.25em]
    \tikzstyle{connection}=[inner sep=0,outer sep=0]
 %Creating Blocks and Connection Nodes
 \coordinate (input);
\node [block, right of=input] (h1) {$0.99$};
 \node [right of=h1] (hsum) {};
    \coordinate[right of=hsum] (cont);
    \path (h1) -- coordinate (hmed) (h1);
    %Connecting Blocks
    \begin{scope}[line width=1pt]
         \draw (input) -- (h1);\draw (h1) -- (cont);
    \end{scope}
 %Creating Blocks and Connection Nodes
\node [block, right of=cont] (m1) {$0.18$};\node [block, right of=m1] (m2) {$0.16$};
 \node [right of=m2] (msum) {};
    \node [connection, right of=msum] (output) {};
    \path (m1) -- coordinate (mmed) (m2);
    %Connecting Blocks
    \begin{scope}[line width=1pt]
         \draw (cont) -- (m1);\draw (m1) -- (m2);\draw (m2) -- (output);
    \end{scope}
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want to stick to the `node`, use `cont.center` for the connections instead of `cont` like:

```
\draw (input) -- (h1);\draw (h1) -- (cont.center);
```

Code again:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}%pictures
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[auto,>=latex']
    \tikzset{block/.style = {draw, shape=rectangle, minimum height=3em, minimum width=3em, node
                              distance=2cm, line width=1pt},
              sum/.style = {draw, shape=circle, node distance=1.5cm, line width=1pt, minimum 
                            width=1.25em},
              connection/.style={inner sep=0,outer sep=0}
    }
 %Creating Blocks and Connection Nodes
 \coordinate (input);
\node [block, right of=input] (h1) {$0.99$};
 \node [right of=h1] (hsum) {};
    \node [connection, right of=hsum] (cont) {};
    \path (h1) -- coordinate (hmed) (h1);
    %Connecting Blocks
    \begin{scope}[line width=1pt]
         \draw (input) -- (h1);\draw (h1) -- (cont.center);
    \end{scope}
 %Creating Blocks and Connection Nodes
\node [block, right of=cont] (m1) {$0.18$};\node [block, right of=m1] (m2) {$0.16$};
 \node [right of=m2] (msum) {};
    \node [connection, right of=msum] (output) {};
    \path (m1) -- coordinate (mmed) (m2);
    %Connecting Blocks
    \begin{scope}[line width=1pt]
         \draw (cont.center) -- (m1);\draw (m1) -- (m2);\draw (m2) -- (output);
    \end{scope}
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Also, use `tikzset` instead of `tikzstyle` (deprecated) as I did in the second code.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by adding some property to `tikzpicture` as follows:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={inner sep=0,outer sep=0}]
```

Comment: This applies to *all* nodes inside the picture and needs to be overwritten for nodes, where the space is needed as for the three rectangular nodes with the numbers. Using `coordinate` instead of `node` is the better choice for denoting a point without node contents.